# Is there a way to convert all comments into javadoc comments? [Eclipse/Java]

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, comments, javadoc

I'm doing a Java school assignment with Eclipse, and at the very bottom it says all documentation should be in Javadoc, but I already did all my comments using `//`.

Is there any easier way to do this other than manually going back and changing every comment to Javadoc format `/** */`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javadocs are a specific comment format used to generate external documentation for your code. You shouldn't be converting regular comments to Javadoc.

For example:

```
/**
 * Do foo with a.
 * @param a the a value
 * @return some different value
 * @see #bar
 */
public String foo(String a) {
    // blah blah blah
}
```

See [this technical doc](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/javadoc-tool.html) for more details.

If you do want to convert the comments, though, you would have to do it manually like you said. There isn't a specific tool for this.

Comment: I see, so for example for something like this:
 
```/** Setting greatestCost to the index of the most expensive transport*/
  for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
   if(allTransports[greatestCost].getTicketPrice() < allTransports[i].getTicketPrice()) {
    greatestCost = i;
   }
  }```
Is this correct use of Javadoc, or should I be using ```//``` instead?

Comment: Damn that did not come out the way I planned. Essentially, if my comment is ```/** Setting greatestCost to the index of the most expensive transport*/ ```

Comment: No, that would be a regular comment. Javadoc is intended for top-level documentation, e.g. classes, methods, and fields. Never inside a method. The technical doc I linked should help a lot.